# Mysql Case Syntax

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM case_study
ORDER BY CASE WHEN expiry_date_case > CURDATE() THEN 1 END
WHEN expiry_date_case IS NULL THEN 2 Desc END
WHEN expire_date_case < CURDATE() THEN 3 Desc END;
```

When I am trying to run this query i am getting error as

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHEN expiry_date_case IS NULL THEN 2 Desc END WHEN
>   expire_date_case < CURDATE() ' at line 4

---

Where am  i doing wrong?

Comment: If the case ain't ending, don't end it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM case_study
ORDER BY CASE WHEN expiry_date_case > CURDATE() THEN 1 
WHEN expiry_date_case IS NULL THEN 2 
WHEN expire_date_case < CURDATE() THEN 3 END Desc
```

You have too many `End`'s and Too many `desc`'s

Answer (score 1):

Update your query into

```
SELECT *
FROM case_study
ORDER BY CASE WHEN expiry_date_case > CURDATE() THEN 1 
WHEN expiry_date_case IS NULL THEN 2 
WHEN expire_date_case < CURDATE() THEN 3 END Desc
```

Removed that `end` and `desc`